# (Python) When I click on 'Edit with IDLE', nothing happens

Tags: python

I have a saved python project which I want to edit, but when I click on 'Edit with IDLE', the dropdown menu closes, then nothing happens.

Comment: Could you give some more information? Has this worked in the past? What version of python are you using? What OS?

Comment: @Randomhero I'm using the most recent version of python, 3.7.4. I'm on Windows 7. I haven't used python on this computer before but I have used python on the same OS and it has worked.